# Display images within a PrimeNG DataTable

Tags: datatable, angular, primeng

I am developing a website using Angular2 and would like to display information in a table.  I am using PrimeNG's [DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).  The problem is I need to display images within the table.  This can be done using PrimeNG's [DataList](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datalist), but DataList's appearance and inability to sort columns keeps me from using it.  Ideas?

Comment: Can you please present a code example so we can look at your problem and provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use templating to place image inside column. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatabletemplating

Comment: Thank you so much mysterious Cagatay Civici!  That does the trick!